# Replacement for ternary operator in template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++03

I am implementing a binomial coefficient (n choose k) function in C++.
Besides using a "normal" function (which is evaluated at runtime) this also can be accomplished using template metaprogramming (when the arguments are known at compile time):

```
template <unsigned int n, unsigned int k>
struct Binomialkoeffizient {
    static const unsigned int value = Binomialkoeffizient<n, k-1>::value * (n-k+1) / k;
};

template <unsigned int n>
struct Binomialkoeffizient<n, 0> {
    static const unsigned int value = 1;
};
```

The drawback of this implementation is, that it does not make use of the theorem n choose k = n choose n-k in the cases where k > n/2. So unnecessary arithmetic overflow may occur, e.g. 49 choose 43 does overflow, whereas 49 choose 6 does not.

I have tried the following to improve this:

```
template <unsigned int n, unsigned int k>
struct Binomialkoeffizient {
    static const unsigned int value = (2*k > n) ? Binomialkoeffizient<n, n-k>::value : Binomialkoeffizient<n, k-1>::value * (n-k+1) / k;
};

template <unsigned int n>
struct Binomialkoeffizient<n, 0> {
    static const unsigned int value = 1;
};
```

Unfortunately, I get `fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900`.

This seems to be caused by the fact, that the ternary operator is not evaluated during the process of recursive template instantiation.

What are possible alternatives to using `?:` ?

I am interested in pre-C++11 solutions and newer solutions alike (maybe `std::enable_if` helps, but I do not know well about it).

Comment: Have you tried using [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this? I am not sure how to use it exactly. It also seems to only work with C++11 upwards.

Comment: @Fabian Yes, it is C++11.  Step 1: solve it in C++11 using `std::conditional`.  Step 2: Write `my::conditional` in C++03.  Step 3: Profit.

Comment: @Yakk Now I finally know what ???? is.

Answer (score 2):

After a night of sleep, I think I got the point with the `std::conditional`.

**Edit:** As @Yakk has proposed, I also have implemented the `conditional` myself.

This implementation works with all C++ standards:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    // in C++11 and above we can use std::conditional which is defined in <type_traits>
    #include <type_traits>
    namespace my {
        using std::conditional;
    }
#else
    // in older C++ we have to use our own implementation of conditional
    namespace my {
        template <bool b, typename T, typename F>
        struct conditional {
            typedef T type;
        };

        template <typename T, typename F>
        struct conditional<false, T, F> {
            typedef F type;
        };
    }
#endif

template <unsigned int n, unsigned int k>
struct Binomialkoeffizient {
    static const unsigned int value = my::conditional< (2*k > n), Binomialkoeffizient<n, n-k>, Binomialkoeffizient<n, k> >::type::_value;
    static const unsigned int _value = Binomialkoeffizient<n, k-1>::_value * (n-k+1) / k;
};

template <unsigned int n>
struct Binomialkoeffizient<n, 0> {
    static const unsigned int value = 1;
    static const unsigned int _value = 1;
};
```

Suggestions on how to make the code more concise or elegant (is it really necessary to use the second static member `_value` ?) are warmly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 introduced the `constexpr` specifier,

> ...(which) declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the
>   function or variable at compile time. Such variables and functions can
>   then be used where only compile time constant expressions are allowed
>   (provided that appropriate function arguments are given). A constexpr
>   specifier used in an object declaration implies const.
>
> *(quoted from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)*

In practice, you can implement a function like this:

```
template<class T>
constexpr T binomial_coefficient(const T n, const T k)
{
    if ( 2 * k > n )
    {
        return binomial_coefficient(n, n - k);
    }
    else
    {
        return k ? binomial_coefficient(n, k - 1) * (n - k + 1) / k : 1;
    }
}
```

That can be evaluated at compile time.
As an example, look at https://godbolt.org/g/b1MgFd where this snippet is compiled by different compilers and the line

```
constexpr auto value = binomial_coefficient(49, 43);
```

Become

```
mov     eax, 13983816
```

Comment: I think that multiple statements in a `constexpr` function is officially added in C++14.

Comment: @Phil1970 You are right. In this particular case it is easily solved by using a single return with another conditional operator instead of the `if` I used.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have verified it by disassembling the object code with `objdump` and indeed the computed value was in the file. Interestingly, immediately using the value without prior assignment to a variable, e.g. `std::cout << binomial_coefficient(49, 43);` causes the value to NOT be computed at compile time.

Comment: @Fabian Yes, please note also that if you declare that variable as `const`, clang doesn't compute it at compile time, while gcc does.

Answer (score 1):

The answer with `constexpr` is the best way to do it assuming you are using a modern C++ compiler.

However, the following code is essentially an improvement of your code that avoid instantiating too much template. In effect, as far as I know when using template as in your example, the compiler will generate all template that are in a ternary expression and not only the one is the selected side.

```
template <unsigned int n, unsigned int k>
struct Binomialkoeffizient 
{
    static const unsigned int k2 = (2 * k > n) ? n - k : k;
    static const unsigned int value = Binomialkoeffizient<n, k2 - 1>::value * (n - k2 + 1) / k2 ;
};

template <unsigned int n>
struct Binomialkoeffizient<n, 0> {
    static const unsigned int value = 1;
};
```

By defining `k2` I can remove one extra level when `2 * k > n` is true.

If you are using a C++ 11 compiler, you could replace `const` by `constexpr`. Otherwise, using an unnamed `enum` might be preferable as otherwise, it is possible that the compiler still reserve memory for `value` member for each instantiation level.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea with the k2. Just in the case n=k, e.g. `Binomialkoeffizient<49, 49>::value` your program does not work, as it perpetuously instantiates new templates until reaching the limit. Adding a further spezialization `template <unsigned int n>
struct Binomialkoeffizient<n, n> {
    static const unsigned int value = 1;
};`helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share my attempt at binomial coefficients in compile time.

```
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned N, unsigned K, typename = unsigned> // last arg for sfinae
struct choose; // predeclaring template for use in choose_recursive

template<unsigned N, unsigned K>
struct choose_recursive // typical recursion for choose is done here
{
    constexpr static unsigned value = choose<N - 1, K - 1>::value + choose<N - 1, K>::value;
};

struct choose_invalid
{
    constexpr static unsigned value = 0;
};

template<unsigned N, unsigned K, typename>
struct choose {
    constexpr static unsigned value = std::conditional_t<
        N >= K, choose_recursive<N, K>, choose_invalid
        >::value;
};

template<unsigned N>
struct choose<N, 0> {
    constexpr static unsigned value = 1;
};

// sfinae to prevent this and previous specialization overlapping for (0, 0)
template<unsigned K>
struct choose <K, K, std::enable_if_t< 0 <  K, unsigned>> {
    constexpr static unsigned value = 1;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << choose<5, 2>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << choose<5, 3>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << choose<20, 10>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << choose<0, 0>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << choose<0, 1>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << choose<49, 43>::value << std::endl;
}
```

This solution will work properly for each choose function value fitting in unsigned type, thus actually fixing the overflowing issues OP has been facing. A bit of sfinae is used to allow only single specialization for choose<0, 0> to match, and std::conditional_t is used to account for cases where N < K.