# Recursion using template meta programming

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Can somebody explain to me, why the first call using the template function  is falling into an infinite loop, while the second compile-time function runs correctly?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int N, int M>
struct commondivs {                                              
  static const int val = (N<M) ? commondivs<N,(M-N)>::val : commondivs<(N-M),M>::val;
};

template<int N>
struct commondivs<N,N> {
  static const int val = N;
};


int commondiv(int N, int M){
    if(N==M){
        return N;
    }   
    return (N<M)?commondiv(N,(M-N)):commondiv((N-M),M);     
}

int main() {

    cout << commondivs<9,6>::val << endl;
    cout << commondiv(9,6) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacement for ternary operator in template metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378031/replacement-for-ternary-operator-in-template-metaprogramming)

Comment: The goal was to used template meta programming. ```constexpr``` is not an option.

Comment: Added c++98 tag to make explicit that `constexpr` is not an option. (It was introduced in C++11). That does invalidate existing answers. Exxul, please clarify which C++ version you're limited to.

Comment: Sorry I removed the tag.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
(N<M) ? commondivs<N,(M-N)>::val : commondivs<(N-M),M>::val
```

This line causes instantiation of both `commondivs<N,(M-N)>::val` and `commondivs<(N-M),M>::val`, even if the condition is known at compile time and one of the branches will never be taken.

Replace `? :` with `std::conditional_t`, which doesn't have this limitation:

```
static const int val = std::conditional_t<N < M, commondivs<N,(M-N)>, commondivs<(N-M),M>>::val;
```

Answer (score 16):

The problem is all the operands of conditional operator will be evaluated, so both `commondivs<N,(M-N)>` and `commondivs<(N-M),M>` get instantiated and their `val` get evaluated and then leads to recursive template instantiation.

You can apply [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) and put it in a `constexpr` `static` member function.

> If the value is `true`, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded.

```
template<int N, int M>
struct commondivs {                                              
  constexpr static int get_val() {
    if constexpr (N<M) return commondivs<N,(M-N)>::val; // if true, the else part won't be evaluated
    else return commondivs<(N-M),M>::val;               // vice versa
  }
  static const int val = get_val();
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/94sxHjSjZ6xwm2TQ)

Comment: Evaluated or just instantiated?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Evaluated; not just instantiated.

Comment: The value of `::val` has to be generated on both branches sure, but this is still instantiation (of a template with a static const member). Evaluation at run time does _not_ happen ... well, it obviously can't since it never compiles ...

Answer (score 8):

The ternary operator is not like `if constexpr`: when a compiler sees it, it has to generate code for both branches. In other words, to instantiate a template `commondivs<M, N>`, a compiler instantiates **both** templates `commondivs<N, M - N>` and `commondivs<N - M, M>`.

In contrast to that, `commondiv(N, M - N)` and `commondiv(N - M, M)` are translated into two function calls. Which one is taken, will be decided when the function is actually called.

**Addition.**

**HolyBlackCat** gave a solution with `std::conditional_t`. Here is another one:

```
template<int N, int M>
struct commondivs {                                              
    static constexpr int min = (N < M) ? N : M;
    static constexpr int max = (N < M) ? M : N;
    static constexpr int val = commondivs<min, max - min>::val;
};

template<int N>
struct commondivs<N, N> {
    static constexpr int val = N;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You get infinite recursion because:

```
static const int val = (N<M) ? commondivs<N,(M-N)>::val : commondivs<(N-M),M>::val;
```

isn't metatemplate programming at all because `?:`, as @Eng says, isn't `constexpr`.

You want to look at @HolyBlackCat's answer.

Comment: It won't help. `?:` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: No I try it. The same infinite loop.